# Limiting IP access geographically

Tags: networking, firewall, cisco

I don't want to cause any offence here, but whenever I take a look at the logs for my servers I can see I am constantly having IP addresses in China try to login to my machines, hoping to get access brute forcing passwords for administrator or admin or root etc.

We're based in the UK, and our servers are also in a UK data centre. We have some IPs we use to access the machines for remote desktop, some for the remote KVM consoles on those machine, one for our main switch which is a Cisco SG200 and has a web control panel. Those admin IPs are only ever going to be legitimately accessed from the UK, but I can't always guarantee what IP address it would be from.

We have some virtual machines hosting websites - they run on different IPs in the same range, but those IPs need to be available globally.

Is there some way I can limit access to certain IPs on a geographic basis? Say for example that any IP that is located in the UK can access it, but other countries cannot? Is there something I can do on the Cisco SG200 to achieve this, or is there some other piece of affordable hardware that can sit in front of my switch that could do it?

Comment: Ask you ISP, 95% of them can do that at the router level for you on a per IP basis.

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to look up ip ranges per country. Google can help you there. These are a lot though, and making individual rules may make your firewall slow. Also, I don't know how to do that in a Cisco SG200, especially when you have one of those webinterfaces that only allow you to enter 10 rules, but using iptables on Linux, it's straightforward enough to create a large amount of firewall rules by using scripts.

Perhaps in your situation, it's better to simply put your admin interface on another port. This won't help much against a targeted attack, but it saves your system having to respond to brute force attacks.

There's a host of other solutions. It's going to be hard to give you a full list. One safe way to regulate admin access, is to use a bounce host and only allow connections from that, or perhaps a (software) firewall in front of it. If you're not in a position to constantly apply software updates, that's a good thing anyway. I don't trust webadmin panels on hardware, myself. [Case in point](http://mis.fortunecook.ie/).

Comment: Have had it confirmed that my switch can't do it - not sure why, network guy says it simply can't. So open to alternative ideas. Want to keep the actual servers setup as clean as possible, so ideally some hardware between the network and my hardware / switch.

Answer (score 1):

Search for GEOIP. you will have ip ranges by provider's countries (key point is here. it's providers country on paper.) Geographic division is actually meanless when we are talking about web. Anyone can have any IP address from anywhere. Also your geoip database must be updated regularly. More over your block list will be a long list. consider that rules will be applied every connection to your system.

There is another way for this, if you are using linux try [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page). for other systems use a [firewall distro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_router_and_firewall_distributions) which most of them has more than fai2ban and IDS / IPS

Comment: Thanks for this. My servers are running Windows, with Hyper V virtual machines on top of them, so something like Fail2Ban isn't really an option without adding some server hardware inbetween, which isn't the craziest idea if we're looking at dedicated hardware anyway.